# git hub and coding processes

Tags: github, coldfusion

Ive been programming for a little while now and have built a little application which is now hosted on a dedicated server.

Now i have been rolling out different versions of my app with no real understanding on how to manage the process properly.

Is this the proper way to manage a build of an application when using a product like git hub ?

1. Upload my entire application onto github.
2. Each time i work on it, download it and install it on my dev server.
3. When im done working on it and it appears to be ok, do i then upload the changed files with the current project i am working on or am i meant to update the entire lot or am i mean to create a new version of the project?
4. once all my changes are updated, is there anyway of pushing these to a production machine from git hub or generating a listing of the newly changed files so i can update production machine easily with a checklist of some kind ?

My application has about 900 files associated with it and is stored in various folder structures and is a server based app (coldfusion to be precise) and as i work alone majority of the time, im struggling to understand how to manage the development of an app...

I also have no idea on using the command line and my desktop machine is a mac, with a VM running all my required server apps (windows server 2012, MSSQL 2012 etc)

I really want to make sure i can keep my dev process in order, but ive struggled with how to understand how to manage a server side apps development when im using a mac my dev machine is a windows machine i feel like im stuck in the middle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You make it sound more complicated than it is.

> Upload my entire application onto github.

Well, this is actually 2 steps: First, create a local git repo (`git init`), then push your repo up to github.

> Each time i work on it, download it and install it on my dev server.

Well, you only need to "download" it once to a new dev box. After that, just `git pull` (or `git fetch` depending on workflow), which ensures any changes on the server are pulled down. Just the deltas are sent.

Git is a *distributed* version control system. That means every git repo has the full history of the entire project. So only deltas need to be sent. (This really helps when multiple people are hacking on a project).

> When im done working on it and it appears to be ok, do i then upload the changed files with the current project i am working on or am i meant to update the entire lot or am i mean to create a new version of the project?

Hmm, you are using fuzzy terminology here. When you are done editing, you first commit locally (`git add ...; git commit`), then you push the changes to github (`git push`). Only the deltas are sent. Every commit is "a new version" if you squint.

Later on, if you want to think in terms of "software releases" (i.e. releasing "version 1.1" after many commits), you can use git tags. But don't worry about that right away.

> once all my changes are updated, is there anyway of pushing these to a production machine from git hub or
>
> generating a listing of the newly changed files so i can update production machine easily with a checklist of some kind ?

Never manually mess around with files manually on your server. The server should ONLY be allowed to run a valid, checked-out version of your software. If your production server is running random bits of code, nobody will be able to reproduce problems because they aren't in the version control system.

The super-simple way to deploy is to do a `git clone` on your server (one time), then `git pull` to update the code.  So you push a change to github, then pull the change from your server.

More advanced, you will want something like **capistrano** that will manage the checkouts for you, and break up "checking out" from "deploying" to allow for easier rollback, etc. There may be windows-specific ways of doing that too. (Sorry, I'm a Linux guy.)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, its made me understand it alot more. many many thanks for this.